# C# OneDrive like extension to Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, cloud, shell-extensions, shared-data

I found this question/solution related to programming OneDrive like extension:

[Creating a special folder in Windows Explorer like DropBox or OneDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328179/creating-a-special-folder-in-windows-explorer-like-dropbox-or-onedrive)

Is it possible to do it in a way that files don't use up local disk space (like they do in OneDrive)? So to have them displayed just by syncing headers/properties and actually downloading the whole file from the cloud when user wants to read/edit it?

*goal: a cloud (shared drive) solution with several TBs in capacity. If files were to be synced then it's no use on laptops (limitation with SSD size)...

Comment: Yes it's possible, but almost not documented. Have a look at this product who exposes two Windows low level APIs: "Files On Demand" and "ProjFS" (Projected File System, used by Microsoft to connect to huge++ github repos): https://www.shellboost.com/Doc/Introduction/Files-On-Demand (disclaimer: I work for the company who sells them). Note that AFAIK dropbox doesn't uses these API, only OneDrive as of today.

Comment: thank you. Are there any open source solutions?

Comment: Not that I know of. And as of today, this is also the only commercial product that has this :-)